# Why does localbattle.net point to localhost?

Tags: certificates, webserver

I found a random link on a forum linking to localbattle.net, at the same time I was running a local server on localhost. When I went to localbattle.net, my local server page appeared! The certificate was invalid, and the *"Your connection is not private" warning* screen appeared. Can that site see the content of my local server (page)? And is it a my client's issue, their server's issue, or my local server's issue?

Comment: Just from the name, it seems to be related to Blizzard's Battle.net. The name "localbattle.net" implies it points to your local battle.net installation.

Comment: Actually, nevermind I found the answer. It's because that site resolves to `127.0.0.1` i.e. `localhost`, just like how Google can resolve to `172.217.25.142`.

Comment: @facepalm42 what is wrong with Google resolving to a public IP address?

Comment: This also works with `something.com`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This domain is used by Blizzard (battle.net) for some communication between their web pages and a server running in localhost.

Thus, when the web page wanted to communicate with the local install, it would direct a request to https://localbattle.net:22886/ were the game would be running a webserver. As they owned the domain, they would have issued a publicly valid certificate for that domain, which could then be embedded in the game, while they couldn't have obtained a certificate for `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`.

Do note however that this was still the wrong thing to do. Since the private key needed to be shared within the game, the *private key* isn't really private, and such certificate MUST be revoked by the CA within 24 hours of knowing about it (section 4.9.1.1 of the [Baseline Requirements](https://cabforum.org/wp-content/uploads/CA-Browser-Forum-BR-1.6.5.pdf)).

The public certificate running locally was originally [reported by Tavis Ormandy](https://twitter.com/taviso/status/938503794098180096) and -after Hanno Böck reported it to [mozilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1425166) and the CA- the [certificate](https://crt.sh/?id=277776142) got revoked, after which Blizzard issued an update that installed a local (non-CA) certificate into the root trust store. Then they briefly used a [new certificate](https://crt.sh/?id=287530764), issued by digicert which also got revoked, and [added to the OneCRL](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1427034).

The whole story is explained quite well on [this mozilla.dev.security.policy thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mozilla.dev.security.policy/pk039T_wPrI/tGnFDFTnCQAJ). If you want to dig up more, you can also read this [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/heroesofthestorm/comments/7lb8vq/hey_blizzard_whats_the_deal_with_this_sneaky_root/), and the [Blizzard post](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/bnet/topic/20760626838) explaining their change to use a self-signed certificate.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ dig 8.8.8.8 localbattle.net
...
localbattle.net.        86400   IN      A       127.0.0.1
```

The above shows that the name resolves globally to 127.0.0.1, i.e. localhost. It is unknown why the setup is this way and the question does not provide sufficient context to find out.

Comment: @MechMK1: not from the `hosts` file but from DNS. Updated to show that also google DNS resolves to this.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Yeah, I just tried it with 8.8.8.8

Comment: 1.1.1.1 is the same: `nslookup localbattle.net 1.1.1.1` `Server: one.one.one.one | Address: 1.1.1.1 | Non-authoritative answer: | Name: localbattle.net | Address: 127.0.0.1`